# OpenCV distanceTransform returns unexpected results (either an empty Mat or original image)

Tags: opencv, distance, transformation

I cannot successfully calculate the distance transformation using OpenCV (2.3) on an ubuntu. The output is either black or a copy of the orignial image, but never as expected an greyscale image with gradients.

My code:

```
Mat input(Size(100,100), CV_8UC1);
circle(input, Point(50,50), 10 Scalar(255,255,255), 15, 0, 0));

Mat output(Size(100,100), CV_32FC1);
distanceTransformation(input, output, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_3); //Output is completely black
//distanceTransformation(input, output, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE); //Output is a "copy" of input


imshow("in", input);
imshow("out", output);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call is correct, but being a distance, it's not stored as uchar. When you want to display it, OpenCV converts those float (i think) into uchars. And the result seems black.

Find the max value in the output, and then scale it to fit a grayscale image

```
double maxVal = findMaxDistanceSomehow(); 

output.convertTo( displayBuffer, CV_8UC1, 255./maxVal,0);

imshow("dist", displayBuffer);
```

**EDIT**

The first idea was correct, but you actually did not try to find maxVal! You said that by looking at the picture, instead of actually extracting it. Difference between win and fail.

So, calculate the dist transform using the **precise** algoritm, and then

```
output.convertTo( displayBuffer, CV_8UC1, 10 ,0);
```

**Edit 2**

And you **must** put the setTo(0) there.

Comment: strange... is your input image black with a white circle? why not set it to zero before painting the circle? input.setTo(0);

Comment: Yeah, my input image is black with a white circle (very small black hole in the center). setTo(0) doesn't change anything (sadly)...

Comment: Options other than CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE return only black results.
Rescaling the PRECISE works! Thank you!